# Which movie adaptation of A Christmas Carol is most faithful to the novella?

Tags: book-adaptation

There are many movie (and indeed TV) adaptations of Charles Dickens’ *A Christmas Carol*, and many reasons to enjoy them for their own interpretation of the story.

But which version can be considered as closest to it being most faithful to the original written story? I understand this could be seen as opinion based so if there can be references to sources of where this might have been discussed before that would be great.

Comment: I'd be hard pressed to choose between the Muppets & Carry On… ;)

Comment: I don’t think it’s opinion based because you could objectively examine every line of dialogue and count whether or not it is present in a specific film version. I’d love to see an answer to this that includes such information about many answers; though it would be a lot of work! Maybe someone has already done it.

Comment: Exactly @Gendolkari, this is what I was hoping someone might have knowledge of!

Comment: @Tetsujin  No - Blackadder nailed it !  :D